# Issue with CORS when sending a get request to external API in - NodeJS / heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have an app built in 'Angular/NodeJs' that using heroku server.
In the app i have a option to search for a movies in 'omdbapi' .Everything works great until i preforming a search, the console giving me the next error:

[image]

When i turn on my CORS extension in chrome it working great.

Can someone please suggest me what is the problem.

node code

```
const express      = require('express');
const bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
const mongoose     = require('mongoose');
const app          = express();
const path         = require('path');
const compression  = require('compression');
const port         = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const cors         = require('cors')

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});

app.use(compression());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "angular")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "angular", "index.html"));
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("App is running on port " + port);
```

[Edit]
Still dot working after changing the header to @jbarros suggestion.

```
const express      = require('express');
const bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
const mongoose     = require('mongoose');
const app          = express();
const path         = require('path');
const compression  = require('compression');
const port         = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Authorization, Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});
```

Angular get function

```
  getMoviesByName(movieName: string) {
    const url = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + movieName + '&apikey=xxxxxxx&type=movie'
    return this.http.get<{Search: ImportedMovieModal[]}>(url)
  }
```

Comment: You must specify headers that you want to use in Access-Control-Allow-Headers fields. May be you have missed to mention some of the headers in Access-Control-Allow-Headers. Also you dont need to specify content-type and Accept in Access-Control-Allow-Headers. They are always allowed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowing the `Authorization` header in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.
So add the header:

Change:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
```

For:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Authorization, Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
```

Also, you probably need to intercept the OPTIONS method to send an HTTP ok status, so:

Change your:

```
next()
```

For:

```
// intercept OPTIONS method
if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.send(200);
} else {
    next();
}
```

And re-deploy it to Heroku.

Comment: @jbaross  Thank you for the help. I edited my question. I cant understand what is the problem there

Comment: @Igorromanovsky do you get the same error after editing? Don't forget restart the server :-)

Comment: @jbaross After  editing i deploying straight to heroku

Comment: @jbaross Thanks for you're help, but it still don't work, maybe its because the get request is getting sent from angular and not from node ? (Added the angular request function)

Comment: Could you post any further info shown by Chrome dev tools in _Network_ tab after re-deploying it to Heroku?

Comment: I added the screenshot.

Comment: @Igorromanovsky I checked the request and it is working fine. Is there something wrong? Regards

Comment: Soory I didn't updated the qustion. I fixed it by creating a route in node and not sending the requst directly from angular. Thank you very much for you're help